# Kubuntu 22.03 access to "Online Accounts" on "System Settings" freezes the "Web authentication for google" window while trying to authenticate

Tags: kubuntu, google, online-accounts, oauth

You can reproduce this issue by opening `System Settings` at Plasma Desktop main menu.

On the left panel you will find the `Online Accounts` section and a button to add a new account. Click on that button and then the Google option. An authentication window will open. Type your user name and click on the `next` button to get asked for your password.
The web dialog will shade and you'll get stuck there.

This has been reported as a bug to kde (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=420280). It seemed to be solved for Neon or Arch at some time in the past, but the bug is still (or reappeared) on Kubuntu 22.04 / 23.04 and there is no additional information anywhere I looked.

Maybe you can guide me on how to solve or workaround this limitation. Anyway, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Install a distro such as Neon or Arch in Qemu or on a separate partition with same username and password.
Add your online account, then copy overwriting the relevant files on your Kubuntu system, such as:

```
~/.config/signond
~/.config/kwallet*
~/.local/share/kwalletd
~/.local/share/keyrings
```

Perhaps some more, that I forgot.

Re-login. Some of your other saved passwords might be lost, but the online account should be there.